# Ubuntu 18.04's Standard Support ended June 2023. ondrej's PPA for php packages not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

First off, I'm no Ubuntu/server expert...to get PHP installed/upgraded on apache2, here's the series of commands I run:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install php8.0 -y
sudo apt install php8.0-common php8.0-mysql php8.0-xml php8.0-xmlrpc php8.0-curl php8.0-gd php8.0-imagick php8.0-cli php8.0-dev php8.0-imap php8.0-mbstring php8.0-opcache php8.0-soap php8.0-zip php8.0-intl -y
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php8.0
```

With the end of standard support for Ubuntu 18.04, ondrej's PHP package support has ended as well:

[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

> Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided.

I receive the following error:

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0'
```

Unfortunately, we're stuck on Ubuntu 18.04 as Amazon Cloud9 doesn't offer anything else and we have dozens of servers running this.

Any help figuring out how to install PHP8+ on Ubuntu 18.04 would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/details/ says "You have the flexibility to run AWS Cloud9 development environments on a managed Amazon EC2 Linux instance or any Linux server that you are using today" so I think you're wrong are it forcing  you to use a Linux distribution from half a decade ago.

Comment: @Quentin there are two methods of using Cloud9, one is to point it at your own non-EC2 server and the other is to use an EC2 server. If you use an EC2 server, you only have the option of their proprietary Amazon Linux 2 version or Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. 

Fact is, we have dozens of servers set up using their Ubuntu 18.04.6 offering so I need to figure out a way to install/upgrade PHP not using ondrej's PPA.

Comment: You might have better luck on https://askubuntu.com since it's about repositories

Comment: Might not be the best, but compiling from source is always (at least theoretically) an option. Or making and distributing your own package.

Answer (score 1):

## Written this as of OCTOBER 2023

Use [this launchpad source](https://launchpad.net/%7Esergey-dryabzhinsky/+archive/ubuntu/php80)

This is for main php module and the packages

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php80
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/backports
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/packages
sudo apt update
```

Install PHP 8.0

```
sudo apt install php80 php80-cli
```

or if you want install this as system php

```
sudo apt install php80p php80-cli
```

Remember that the PHP is just standing alone without any common library !
So, add either one of these too. Recommended the php8-modules

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php-modules
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php7-modules
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php8-modules
```

To install the extension, just add word **mod** between php and the extension name

```
sudo apt install php8-mod-openssl
sudo apt install php8-mod-zip
sudo apt install php8-mod-unzip
sudo apt install php8-mod-curl
sudo apt install php8-mod-dom
```

Or you can use this built in tools `php-modset` or `php80-modset` to enable disable library.

I'm just facing the same situation, and here's my thoughts :

*"I know maintaining legacy code / system cannot be avoided sometimes. Even a central banking system still using Jurassic language COBOL and Jurassic era IBM server. And ain't nobody wants to pay US$ 50,000 to upgrade the working system if they can pay US$ 500 just to add some cherry on cake"*